# How to integrate without using trigonometric substitution: $\int{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}}dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I integrate the following *without* using Trigonometric substitution?
$$\int{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}}dx$$
I tried substituting, $t = 1 - x^4$ but that didn't work. The solution according to my book is
$$\frac{1}{2}\arcsin{\left(x^2\right)}+C$$

Comment: You can't. You can perform the change of variable $y=x^2$ but you need $\displaystyle \int_0^x \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt=\arcsin x$ that is, to perform the change of variable $t=\sin x$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factorize $1-x^4$ to $(1-x^2)(1+x^2)$. Substitute $t=x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Put $x$ square equal to $t$.